# Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on autocomplete prior to initialization; attempted to call method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete, symfony-1.4

Regarding the answer to [Error: cannot call methods on autocomplete prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549126/error-cannot-call-methods-on-autocomplete-prior-to-initialization-attempted-to), apparently I need to ask as a new question! I am trying to use the Symfony sfWidgetFormJQueryAutocompleter plugin which uses the Jquery autocomplete library, the PHP render function for the JS is as follows.  Where would I add the $(this.target).find('input').autocomplete() line mentioned in the above post in the below code?

```
sprintf(<<<EOF
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#%s")
    .autocomplete('%s', jQuery.extend({}, {
      dataType: 'json',
      parse:    function(data) {
        var parsed = [];
        for (key in data) {
          parsed[parsed.length] = { data: [ data[key], key ], value:     data[key], result: data[key] };
        }
        return parsed;
      }
    }, %s))
    .result(function(event, data) { jQuery("#%s").val(data[1]); });
  });
</script>
EOF
      ,
      $this->generateId('autocomplete_'.$name),
      $this->getOption('url'),
      $this->getOption('config'),
      $this->generateId($name)
    );
```

Comment: I have looked through all the forums and nobody seems to indicate where this should be added.  Standard Symfony 1.4 plugin for autocomplete and JQuery / JQuery UI loaded nothing else has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```php
    return $this->renderTag('input', array('type' => 'hidden', 'name' => $name, 'value' => $value)).
           parent::render('autocomplete_'.$name, $visibleValue, $attributes, $errors).
           sprintf(<<<EOF
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#%s")
    .autocomplete('%s', jQuery.extend({}, {
      dataType: 'json',
      parse:    function(data) {
        var parsed = [];
        for (key in data) {
          parsed[parsed.length] = { data: [ data[key], key ], value: data[key], result: data[key] };
        }
        return parsed;
      }
    }, %s))
    .result(function(event, data) { jQuery("#%s").val(data[1]); });
  });

  // manually trigger autocomplete
  jQuery("#%s").find('input').autocomplete();
</script>
EOF
      ,
      $this->generateId('autocomplete_'.$name),
      $this->getOption('url'),
      $this->getOption('config'),
      $this->generateId($name),
      $this->generateId('autocomplete_'.$name)
    );
  }
```